# Backup and Restoration Strategy for Cassandra 3.11

Tags: cassandra, nosql, backup

We are working on Cassandra backup restoration strategy, **currently having 9 node cluster with replication factor 3**. So we are backing up Global cluster with nodetool snapshot for all keyspaces sstable. We get snapshot folder for each keyspace on each node.

We are now interested to know the best way of restoration mostly using sstableloader.

So should I take backup/restoration node to node or take one node snapshot backup and restore to multi-node cluster using sstableloader?

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html#toolsBulkloader_t__bulkloader-using-sstableloader